# BigQuery: Query to GroupBy Array Column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have (2) columns in BigQuery table:

1. url

2. tags

**URL** is a single value, and **TAGS** is an array(example below):

**row** | **URL**     | **TAGS**
1      | x.com | donkey
                     | donkey
                     | lives
                     | here

How can I group by TAGS array in BigQuery?

What's the trick to get the following query working?

```
SELECT TAGS FROM `URL_TAGS_TABLE` 
group by unnest(TAGS)
```

I have tried group by [TO_JSON_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string) but it does not give me the desired results

I'd like to see the following output

x.com | donkey | count 2

x.com | lives  | count 1

x.com | here   | count 1

Comment: Given that sample row, what is the expected output?

Comment: i made an edit to my question for the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
   SELECT 'x.com' url, ['donkey','donkey','lives','here'] tags UNION ALL
   SELECT 'y.com' url, ['abc','xyz','xyz','xyz'] tags 
)
SELECT url, tag, COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(tags) tag
GROUP BY url, tag
```

with result

```
Row url     tag     count    
1   x.com   donkey  2    
2   x.com   lives   1    
3   x.com   here    1    
4   y.com   abc     1    
5   y.com   xyz     3
```

Comment: @MachineLearning - great. consider voting up the answers that helped. this is equally important on SO!